# Symfony2 Two conflicted authentication listeners

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony, listener

I have created custom authentication. But for the reasons me unknown there are two active authentication listeners. So authentication provider manager is called Twice.

Firsty `AuthListener` is called, and it runs mu `AuthenticationProviderManager` which returns correct Token. Then `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` is called which runs `AuthenticationProviderManager` again. And it returns "bad credentials".

**How can I "disable" `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`? So only my custom listener is called?**

Security:

```
providers:
    api:
       id: api_user_provider  

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        user: true
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /check_login                
        logout: ~
```

Services:

```
    api_user_provider:
        class:  Ad\FrontendBundle\Security\User\UserProvider
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
    user.security.authentication.provider:
       class:  Ad\FrontendBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\AuthProvider
       arguments: ['', %kernel.cache_dir%/security/nonces]
    user.security.authentication.listener:
       class:  Ad\FrontendBundle\Security\Firewall\AuthListener
       arguments: ["@security.context", "@security.authentication.manager"]
```

Factory

```
class ApiFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
    public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
    {
        $providerId = 'security.authentication.provider.user.'.$id;
        $container
            ->setDefinition($providerId, new DefinitionDecorator('user.security.authentication.provider'))
            ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
        ;
        $listenerId = 'security.authentication.listener.user.'.$id;
        $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('user.security.authentication.listener'))
        ;
        return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
    }    

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'pre_auth';
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
    {}
}

class AdFrontendBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
        $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new ApiFactory());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I know I'm a little late answering but here is how you do.

In your factory you have this function

```
public function getKey()
{
    return 'user';
}
```

This is the key to the config. In the Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\FormLoginFactory (the class that enables UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener) you have this function:

```
public function getKey()
{
    return 'form-login';
}
```

So if you have a look at your security.yml

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    user: true
    form_login:  # <--- This is where you enables the default factory
      login_path: /login
      check_path: /check_login                
    logout: ~
```

You don't want to specify "form_login". This is where you enable UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener. A good default config would be:

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    user: true              
    logout: ~
```

This should be simpler to config in Symfony2.4 according to Fabien's [blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stopPropagation function
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Event.html#method_stopPropagation

```
$event->stopPropagation()
```

Furter information can be found here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#stopping-event-flow-propagation